# How to prevent UILabel from glueing last 'short' word to the previous one?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I noticed that `UILabel` doesn't wrap words fairly. It glues the last short word (10 or less characters) to the previous one and moves them together on the second line.

Check the illustration:
[image]

**Label #1:** There is enough room in the first line for word 'seven' (as expected).

**Label #2:** One more 'short' word added and word 'seven' migrated to the second line (I'd like to avoid this behaviour).

**Label #3:** The last word contains 10 characters and still is treated as 'short' by the Label.

**Label #4:** The last word contains 11 characters and is now detached from word 'seven' that goes back to the first line (as expected).

Seemingly, Apple fights with 'widows' and forces to a 'good typography' by this behaviour. But sometimes I don't need such care. So, how can I prevent `UILabel` from glueing last words to the previous one?

Comment: A extremely minor observation: I might suggest that your “UPD” might be better posted as a separate answer, rather than as an edit to your question. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: This was done in iOS 11 to prevent orphaned words.  You can turn this behavior off using the answer below or you can use a UITextview or CATextLayer and manually calculate your font size. With these the wrap will be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using `NSAllowsDefaultLineBreakStrategy` set to `false`.
[image]

Comment: This seems not to be working any more in iOS 13 (just noticed in Simulator, I have not done a lot of testing yet).

Answer (score -2):

Most fonts on iOS/macOS are proportional and the typeface system attempt to use good typography standards. Therefore the characters and/or typography will change the spacing based on other characters around it, line length etc. To get more predictable text display, use a font that has fixed spacing like Monaco or other fixed spacing fonts. This will produce a much more predictable display.

Here is Apple's Typography guidelines to start at:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/

Comment: That's not a font issue. Here is a monospaced font: https://monosnap.com/direct/oA0utzBYkbEEhdTWutGuAgudkpXJd3 Also, I've checked in TextEdit app on MacOS, there is no such feature: https://monosnap.com/direct/7MtMQaeEXN49WOUvT62hUVEeciOLRH So I still blame UILabel for some not documented behaviour.